# nothing happens after sorting in Android

Tags: android, arrays, listview, sorting

```
public void addListenerOnSorting() {

    sorting=(Button) findViewById(R.id.sort);

    sorting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final  File f = new File(dp);
            File[] files = f.listFiles();
            Arrays.sort(files, filecomparator);
        }
        Comparator<File> filecomparator = new Comparator<File>(){
            public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
                return String.valueOf(file1.getName()).compareTo(file2.getName());
            }
        };
    });
}
```

my problem is that y isn't my listview getting updated or refreshed after sorting?

```
package but.view.apply;

public class homes  extends ListActivity {

    protected static final ArrayAdapter<String> List = null;
    private List<String> item = null;
    private List<String> path = null;
    private String root="/";
    private String back = "../";
    File fifo;
    File f;
    File currentFolder;
    int len;
    Stack<File> history;
    String dp;

    private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> list;
    ArrayAdapter<String>directoryList;
    Button homing,editing,uping,viewing,sorting;
    Button mb, bm,so, wp, lt, st;
    private TextView myPath;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.homemain);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title);

        ImageView entro=(ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.header);
        entro.setSelected(true);
        RunAnimations();
        myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);
        addListenerOnediting();
        addListenerOnButton();
        addListenerOnviewing();
        addListenerOnSorting();

        getDir(root);
    }
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        homing = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home);

        homing.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, homes.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


    private void getDir(String dirPath)
    {
        myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);

        item = new ArrayList<String>();

        path = new ArrayList<String>();

        dp=dirPath;
        final  File f = new File(dirPath);

        File[] files = f.listFiles();

        back = f.getParent();
        uping = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up);

        uping.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getDir(back);
            }
        });

        for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            len=files.length;

            File file = files[i];

            path.add(file.getPath());

            if(file.isDirectory())
                item.add(file.getName() + "/");

            else
                item.add(file.getName());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =

                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.homerow, item);

        setListAdapter(fileList);
        fileList = list;
    }


    @Override

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        File file = new File(path.get(position));

        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            if(file.canRead())
                getDir(path.get(position));
        }
        else
        {
            fifo=file;
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + file.getPath());
            String fname=file.getName();

            if(fname.endsWith(".jpg")||fname.endsWith("png")||fname.endsWith(".gif")||
                    fname.endsWith(".      jpeg"))
            {          intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);      }
            else if(fname.endsWith(".mp4")||fname.endsWith(".3gp"))
            {          intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
                startActivity(intent);      }      else if(fname.endsWith(".mp3"))
            {          intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/*");
                startActivity(intent);      }
        }
    }


    public  void addListenerOnSorting() {

        sorting=(Button) findViewById(R.id.sort);
        final Context context1=this;
        sorting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (v == findViewById(R.id.sort)) {

                    if (fileList != null) {
                        final  File f = new File(dp);

                        File[] fileList = f.listFiles();
                        List<File> directoryListing = new ArrayList<File>();
                        directoryListing.addAll(Arrays.asList(fileList));
                        Collections.sort(directoryListing, new SortFileName());
                        Collections.sort(directoryListing, new SortFolder());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void addListenerOnediting() {

        final Context context = this;

        editing = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit);

        editing.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final CharSequence[] items = {"copy","delete","move","paste","rename"};

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                builder.setTitle("Pick an item");

                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }


    public void addListenerOnviewing() {

        final Context context2 = this;

        viewing = (Button) findViewById(R.id.view);

        viewing.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final CharSequence[] items = {"list", "grid"};

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context2);

                builder.setTitle("View by");

                builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    // Click listener
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                        if(items[item]=="grid")
                        {

                        }
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                //display dialog box
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void RunAnimations() {
        ImageView entro = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header);
        Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animator.ani);
        entro.clearAnimation();
        entro.startAnimation(a);
    }
}
```

now this another alternative that i tried...
the SortFileName class is:

```
package but.view.apply;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SortFileName implements Comparator<File> {
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        return f1.getName().compareTo(f2.getName());
    }
}
```

and the Sortfoldername class is:

```
package but.view.apply;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SortFolder implements Comparator<File> {

    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        if ((f1.isDirectory() && f2.isDirectory())
                || (!f1.isDirectory() && !f2.isDirectory()))
            return 0;
        else if (f1.isDirectory() && !f2.isDirectory())
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have apply niotifydatasetchanged to your listview ?

Comment: yea i tried that too..but no use at all :( its quiet urgent..

Comment: Can you please post your listview code please ?

Comment: i just want to see the listview and its adpater . it is helpful to us if you show more code  . One more thing is this sorted array is associated with your listview ? Your listview not changed if you change another array which is not associated with your current listview.

Comment: so now wat is the mistake that im doing?

Comment: after doing sorting you need to apply new sorted array list to fileList and then after call notify data set changed method .

Comment: and how do i do that?? cud u help by some code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i really don't know what you are doing. this works fine.

```
package my.test.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class AndroidTestActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {
    private List<String> mList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mList = new ArrayList<String>();
        mList.add("bbb");
        mList.add("aaa");
        mList.add("ddd");
        mList.add("ccc");

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mList);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void sort(){
        Collections.sort(mList);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button:
            sort();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there..i cannot add files on my own..its a file explorer..so i have to sort the fils of sdcard for instance..then wat should i do?? this wont work right..because diff files are present on sdcard.. i shudnt define items on my own..

Comment: dude, of course you don't add the items statically, this is just an example to show that the sorting principle works. instead of adding them like that, you add the file names from your filesystem. it just needs to be always the same list instance. you can also completely clear it and add new items if you like...

Answer (score 0):

if anything on your data changes (add or remove an item, sorting or whatever) you need to call notifyDataChanged() on your ListAdapter.

**[edit]**
you have to do something like this

```
class MyList extends ListActivity {
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private List<String> mList;
    ....

    public void onCreate(){
        mList = createMyList();
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.homerow, mList);
        // get sort button
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Collections.sort(mList);
                mAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged(); // you have to do that in the UI thread!
                ....
```

Comment: actually i am using a file explorer so i have to add this sort button where in the lists shud get sorted..i have used notifydatasetchanged() nothing happens..

Comment: in the code that you've posted, you're sorting an array that is never associated with a list. can you publish more code?

Comment: try first to sort your items ArrayList [Collections.sort(items)] and then call notifyDatasetChanged() on the adapter. you are creating a new ArrayList in your code that is not related to the list.

Comment: tried wateva u told..no use..no errors but after i click the button, the list does not update.. :( i have written mList= new ArrayList<String>(); is that right???

Comment: yup, you create the arraylist, fill it with the values that you wanna display, add the list as parameter to the arrayadapter and then set the adapter as listadapter for your list.

Answer (score 0):

For updating your ListView if you have removed or added data in the array which is used with the adapter, then refresh your adapter with:

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i havent added or removed anyhting...i am trying to sort the files which are displayed in listview..i.e simple file explorer

Comment: but if u have updated ur array like swaping 2 and 4 item than also u have to notify ur adapter

Comment: please avoid using abbreviations such as *u* and *ur*